# What's a good Systems Interface Specification template?

Tags: interface-design

A client has a number of disparate systems that they are planning to link together and have asked for a set of system interface specifications that would document the data and protocols used to interface the different parts.

The interfaces are between processes not between users.

Any recommendations for a template that we could use to document the system interfaces?

Answer (score 1):

This book might have the sort of guidance you're looking for: [Enterprise Integration Patterns: Designing, Building, and Deploying Messaging Solutions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321200683)